# Modelo Probabilistico

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, model, predicción

estoy creando un modelo probabilistico en R para predecir un partido de tenis. Como es mi primera vez haciendo uno nose si tengo muy claro el concepto de como crear uno. Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

Ya con la data cargada ejecute el siguiente código:

```
modelo_prob <- glm(Resultado ~  Aces + DobleFalta + Servicios + Breaks + Minutos, 
                   data = data_comb, 
                   family = binomial)

summary(modelo_prob)
```

Con el summary obtuve que las variables servian para predecir la variable Resultado, por lo que le indique al modelo que empezara a hacer predicciones de la siguiente manera:

```
probabilidades <- predict(modelo_prob, type = "response")
```

Luego filtre los resultados por un umbral (eleji el 0,5 pero nose si es lo correcto) y le asigne valores según era mayor o menor al umbral:
umbral <- 0.5

```
prediccion_binaria <- ifelse(probabilidades > umbral, 1, 0)
```

Luego empeze a analizar con diferentes métricas de evaluación el resultado de mi modelo y me dio que predecia bastante bien:

```
confusion_matrix <- table(prediccion_binaria, data_comb$Resultado)

confusionMatrix(confusion_matrix)
```

Y por último gráfique todo:

```
matriz <- matrix(c(1467, 480, 356, 1671), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(Valor = as.numeric(matriz), 
                 Columna = rep(c(0, 1), each = 2), 
                 Fila = rep(c(0, 1), 2))

df$Resultado <- ifelse(df$Fila == df$Columna, "Correcto", "Incorrecto")

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(Fila), y = as.factor(Columna), fill = Resultado)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor), vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5, size = 10, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red")) + # Define los colores manualmente
  labs(title = "Matriz de Confusión", x = "Resultado Real", y = "Predicción") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Hay algunas partes que no detalle porque estoy mas interesado en saber si esto se considera un modelo probabilistico.

Comment: No entiendo a dónde apunta tu pregunta, de hecho no sé si hay una pregunta. Tal vez ayude si te digo algunas cosas, el 0.5 es el umbral de corte que se suele usar en estos modelos (en tu caso "logit")  pero nada te impide modificar este umbral y generar otros resultados. Y sí es un modelo probabilístico, el modelo en sí es `modelo_prob ` y podría usarse de manera descriptiva o luego mediante `predict()` de manera "inferencial". El paso a paso es  la forma habitual en que se enseñan a usar estos modelos

Comment: Hola, mi duda era si el paso a paso estaba bien logrado, ya que lo hice por mi cuenta consultando varias fuentes. Ya se que falta mucho contexto para saber si el modelo que cree funciona correctamente, pero tenia mucha incertidumbre de lo que estaba haciendo. Me quedo más tranquilo si esta es la forma habitual de enseñar a usar estos modelos. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El paso a paso, está bien, al menos es el que he visto que siempre se aplica en la teoría